# Xterm ignores the specificed font, while applying the correct size

Tags: fonts, xterm

Fellow people of the internet,

I encounter an issue with Xterm, as it doesn't want to take into account the font i specify.
I use xinitrc and Xressources, as followed :

```
 XTerm*reverseVideo: on
 xterm*FaceName:     "hack"
 XTerm*FaceSize: 15
```

I can change the font size, but not the actual font, either font or FaceName is used. However, i can change it when i launch i new term with xterm -fa "name".
I don't get what is wrong, and since i'm quite inexperienced with Xterm, i come here seeking for help.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use quotes in `~/.Xresources`:

```
xterm*FaceName:     hack
```

- `hack` is the name of the installed font, not `"hack"`

Answer (score 1):

That's a (mis)feature of fontconfig: if it doesn't find a suitable match, it'll use the default (monospace, etc), without returning an error.  It's not a problem with xterm...

You can use xterm's [`-report-fonts`](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#OPTIONS:-report-fonts) option to see what xterm sees as the fonts that are set.  If the characters that you're printing aren't in the font, xterm will fall-back to whatever fontconfig provides.

You might be able to see the problem also using `fc-list`, e.g., to check the font family-name.

Comment: So is there a difference between using -fa option and setting it into the file , except of course the sustainibility of the config? Is fontconfig overriden of some sort when using -fa  ?

Comment: The [`-fa` option](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#OPTIONS:-fa) sets the resource, so there's no difference.